# Linux bash script to extract data from file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract data from file 1 and paste this data in another file.

File 1 looks like this:

```
[order1]
Amount              4
HappyMeal           yes;
Sex                 "m"
Name                "Jack"

[order2]
Amount              1
HappyMeal           yes;
Sex                 "f"
Name                "Mary"

[order3]
Amount              3
HappyMeal           no;
Sex                 "f"
Name                "Mary"
```

Some lines (not all) of each customer should be pasted into file 2 like this:

```
Customer    "Jack"   yes    m

Customer    "Mary"   yes    f
Customer    "Mary"   no     f
```

I played around with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
ORDER_NR=`grep -o order[0-9]* file1`

for i in $ORDER_NR
do
    CUST_NAME=`awk -v RS='' '/\y${ORDER_NR}\y/' file1`

    echo "$CUST_NAME" >>file2
done
```

For some reason, I only get an empty file.

Eventually, I want sed to replace a variable in an template file.

Any idea why I keep getting an empty file? I think it should at least echo the `CUST_NAME` variable in file 2.

Answer (score 0):

give this line a try:

```
awk -v RS='\\[[^]]*\\]' 'NF{print "Customer",$8,$4,$6}' file
```

It gives:

```
Customer "Jack" yes; "m"
Customer "Mary" yes; "f"
Customer "Mary" no; "f"
```

It is not exactly same as your output. However it would be a good point to start for you. Do some adjustment you will get what you want.